# Multiplication in Ruby on Rails Model of nil values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have several calculated values as part of my risk.rb model

```
before_save :calculate_risk
def calculate_risk
  self.risk1_total = self.component1 * self.component2 * self.component3
  self.risk2_total = self.component4 * self.component5 * self.component6
  ...
end
```

I want to be able to create a risk without filling out the form completely thus each of those components would be nil. So this method creates an error because * is not a valid method for a nil. What is the best way to handle this? I have considered

```
def calculate_risk
  if self.component1.nil? || self.component2.nil? || self.component3.nil?
    self.risk1_total = self.component1 * self.component 2 * self.component3
  elsif ...
end
```

However, this is obviously inefficient and repetitive. I also considered initializing all of these values, though I do not know the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: If you want a zero result if any is nil you can covert it to integer: nil.to_i => 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
before_save :calculate_risk
def calculate_risk
  self.risk1_total = [self.component1,self.component2,self.component3].compact.inject(:*)
  self.risk2_total = [self.component4,self.component5,self.component6].compact.inject(:*)
  ...
end
```

This is assuming you want nil values to just be dropped from the calculation. This will give a result of `nil` if all values are `nil`. You could replace the `nil`s with zeroes if you prefer. You may also be interested in the `:reject` method or other cools tools in the Ruby Array and Enumerable classes.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Two follow ups. So the code you are displaying here will multiply the components but will drop any nil values from the calculation? Also, Is there a benefit to replacing any nil values with 0 in the code as opposed to the methodology shown here?

Comment: It depends on what you intend the default value to be. If a value is missing should it represent a 1 or a 0 (or something else)? If 1, then this code works as is. If 0, then you'll want to do something more.

Comment: So this method seems to work for the risks with 3 components. When I drop to only 2 components in the calculation it seems to give me the same error regarding * being an invalid method on mil classes.

Comment: That's strange. It seems to work in irb. Are you sure you didn't reorder `compact` and `inject` or have some typo in the array declaration?